# How to access javascript variable in laravel syntax in javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel, datatable

I am using jquery datatable in laravel and i want to set character limit 255 of string(row.solution) in datatable row please help me answer would be appreciated thanks in advance

```
{data: 'problem', name: 'problem.problem'},
       {
         data:function(row)
      {
                        return '{!!str_limit('"+row.solution+"',255)  !!}'

       }
 }
```

Comment: This can be done totally in JS, no need to include Laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return row.problem.substr(0, 100)+"..."
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Javascript

```
data:function(row)
 {
    if (row.solution.length > 255) {
     var res = row.solution.substring(0, 255);
     return  res + "...";
    } else {
     return  row.solution;
   }
}
```

Comment: `res` is not defined if `row.solution.length <= 255`.